# Order page is not updating after deleting item from order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Before removing an item from the item lists, I need to delete the item from another database. This is working fine. The problem is an item is removing from woocommerce also, but page content is not updating—every time, I need to reload the page manually to see the changes. If I'm not using the hook, this automatically removes the list, but this is not happening automatically whenever I'm using the hook.

My code snippet

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_delete_order_item', 'remove_item_from_qm_shared_db');

function remove_item_from_qm_shared_db($item_id){
    global $qm_db_link;
    $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_item_id( $item_id );
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);


    // Find QM order id
    $qm_order_id = get_post_meta($order_id, '_qm_order_id', true);
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $single_item_id => $item) {
        if($item_id === $single_item_id ) {
            $product = $item->get_product();
            $sku = $product->get_sku();
            $sku_size_arr = explode("-", $sku);

            $check_qm_product = trim($product->get_meta('qm_inventory_type'));
            if(!empty($check_qm_product)) {
                $qm_db_link->query("DELETE FROM orderproducts WHERE OrderId = {$qm_order_id} AND Sku = '{$sku_size_arr[0]}' AND `Size` = '{$sku_size_arr[1]}'");
                $qm_db_link->close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When clicking on x, the item is deleted from both woo-commerce and second DB, but page content is not updating. It still appears on the page; I need to reload the page to see the changes. I need to work as it was before adding the hook. The item was removed from the list automatically

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I've tested the hook you're using with some of the functions you're using (like wc_get_order, etc...), it all seems to work flawlessly and the page content is updating. 
The part that is [not testable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is the external database which lacks details on how this is applied. 
I think something is going wrong at some point, have you looked at your log files yet? Isn't there an error message by chance?

Comment: After this line $order->get_items() it's not working. Otherwise if using return true, UI is updating.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have fixed the issue. Here is the optimized code. UI is updating as it was.

```
     function remove_item_from_qm_shared_db($item_id){
        global $qm_db_link;
        $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_item_id( $item_id );
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

        // Find QM order id
        $qm_order_id = get_post_meta($order_id, '_qm_order_id', true);
        if($order){
            $item = $order->get_item($item_id);
            $sku_size_arr = explode("-", $item->get_product()->get_sku());
            $qm_db_link->query("DELETE FROM orderproducts WHERE OrderId = '{$qm_order_id}' AND Sku = '{$sku_size_arr[0]}' AND `Size` = '{$sku_size_arr[1]}'");
        }

        return true;
    }
```